# ckeditor and the paste text event

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Can anyone tell meet how to hook into only the paste as text event?

I have tried this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    ev.editor.on('paste', function (evt) {
        alert('Paste Event....');
    });

    ev.editor.on('pastetext', function (evt) {
        alert('Paste Text Event....');
    });
});
```

However the only event i get is the Paste regardless of which of the Paste options I choose...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook to paste event and check whether it was invoked by paste as plain text. This can be done by investigating event's data property.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    ev.editor.on('paste', function (evt) {
        if(evt.data.text) {
            // data was pasted as plain text
        }
    });
});
```